# Best way to display Ruby code on a Web page?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting

What is the best tool to display Ruby code on a Web page ?

How do you do that?

(something like 
http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/stackoverflow-cool-ruby-questions-4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which syntax-highlighter with export to HTML (for blog) to choose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112314/which-syntax-highlighter-with-export-to-html-for-blog-to-choose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pygments. It is a tool in python to display hundreds of different language http://pygments.org/, so also ruby.

Answer (score 7):

There are very many such tools. Stack Overflow uses [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). If you like the format of code posted here, you might want to use. Ruby sample:

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-ruby">
def sum(n)
    result = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= n
        result += i
        i += 1
    end
    return result
end
</pre>
```

The result will look like this:

```
def sum(n)
    result = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= n
        result += i
        i += 1
    end
    return result
end
```

Comment: I do not see any "lang-ruby" in there: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src. What am I missing?

Comment: @Eduardo Those are languages not natively supported by prettify - hence the language extensions. Ruby is natively supported (though not a thorough implementation) hence you do not see a ruby extension in the URL you gave.
Refer line 1353-1358 (or grep ruby) in `src/prettify.js` file to see that I mean

Answer (score 0):

The page you've linked to is a wordpress blog that appears to be using the [wp-syntax wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/). If you search for "syntax highlighter" or "syntax highlighting", you can find something that will work with your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I like google code prettify project:
http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Note, if you are using rails, you will likely have to use the simple_format view helper for the code to display.

```
<%= simple_format(@blogpost) %>
```